# Jupyter installation on Mac OS El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, pip, jupyter

I want to install jupyter, but am trying to this locally.

I don't want to use anaconda or install an additional python with

```
brew install python
```

I write

```
pip install --user jupyter
```

That succeeds. But the installation `jupyter` is not in `$PATH`, so I get

```
$ jupyter notebook
zsh: command not found: jupyter
```

I am using zsh, btw...

What should I do? What to add to `$PATH`?

Comment: Should be in `$HOME/.local/bin`

Comment: No such a directory.
However,
``$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`` contains smth.

Comment: `$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin` then it is

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs explains why you can find it there.

Comment: Thank you for a link!
If a write
``export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/lib``

to ``~/.zshrc`` and restart ``zsh``
I still can't start jupyter:
 ``$ jupyter notebook
    zsh: command not found: jupyter``

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls $HOME/Library/Python/2.7`? The binary should be in `bin`, not `lib`

Comment: Thank you!
I added just ``$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin`` to and was able to ``$PATH`` start ``jupyter``.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't execute an installed python package directly in OS X. Try:

```
python -m "package name" param / options
```

From python -h (help)

```
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

e.g.

```
python3 -m "jupyter" notebook
```

Please note that the python version can vary. If you installed jupyter with another python version replace python3 with that version.

On OS X the default python version is 2.7x. You should not have to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed this by **pip3** then you have to symlink this one. 
I used both El Capitan and Sierra installations, and the procedure was:
Fire up Terminal.app or iTerm (whichever you use)

```
vi ~/.profile
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
```

Exit vi by pressing ESC and then typing `:wq`
Then type `source .profile`
Now your jupyter command will work no matter in which folder you are.

Answer (score 1):

jupyter notebook sets it path depending how you have installed. Either `conda` or `pip/pip3` I installed my notebook from `pip3` 
For Instance you can temporarily switch to **bash** by `exec bash -l` and locate the bin by the following

```
which jupyter
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/jupyter
```

copy the bin path and switch to `zsh`, edit the `.zshrc` and the the following

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:$PATH
```

Or append to your existing $PATH. Restart terminal. Make sure the jupyter bin is correct, it should be different if you have used conda to install jupyter.